Is a rapidly turning on and off water sensor in A/C pan bad wiring or a bad sensor?
I have an AG-1250E water sensor in the pan of my upstairs AC. It was installed 10 years ago, but recently saved me an overflow. I have an issue though, that when this product trips, it starts turning on and off every 3/4 seconds or so. The end result is that the compressor also turns on and off outside and causes power issues visible in some lights in the house. I am sure this is harmful and not intended. My questions is:
Is this likely a bad sensor, or simply bad wiring by the tech? The county inspector made them come back and add a pan later, so I have a feeling it could have been done improperly at first, but I can't find any reference to someone else having this issue.

I was correct in thinking it was improper wiring. This device appears to be solid state in nature. There was very clear instructions and even a red flag on the wire noting which side had to go to the thermostat to break the power connection to the control board. In spite of all of this, the original installer did it backwards. Once I flipped it around, it worked perfectly when submerged in water and my Nest thermostat warned me of the broken connection. I am only surprised it worked at all when backwards, flickering or not, but the flickering did allow us to find it much faster.

You should not have overflow multiple times
Your drain is not working properly.
Those drains are notorious for mold growth that restricts the flow.
To remedy I clean the drain once a year.
To do that I close the pipe at the end and fill it up with diluted bleach and let it soak for a while.

Yes, I have been working on it. It's a 3 story drain line and has been used for almost 40 years. The clog is very stiff due to having to build up under 3 stories of pressure. I increased flow, but have used vinegar, hot water and a shop vac down below.
One note: Be careful with that bleach. I've heard the fumes can cause your metal to corrode. I know with stainless, it's great at reacting with the chromium and making it able to rust. Not sure about other types of steels.

@David glad we agree on what the problem is, good luck solving it, thanks for the tip on bleach

It's possible that the water level is just on the line where it triggers the sensor, the pump starts, the first bit drawn out lowers the water below the sensor, the pump stops, and some water flows back to trigger the sensor again. The pump should have a check valve to limit backflow, but may not, or the check valve may be stuck.
If you want to fix this yourself, I think you really need to observe it in operation and see exactly how the water level is behaving.

I've had it overflow multiple times and emptied it down a couple times. I may just drop it in a water cup to be sure, but I'm 95% sure it will do it at any water level

Well, it was a thought.
